# In R - How to plot a PDF and CDF for exponential distribution given lambda=0.2 or theta=5 and N=10?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution, exponential

I don't know how to plot the probability distribution function (PDF) and the cumulative one given `λ = 1/5` for `N=10`observations

Comment: The pdf and cdf are independent of the number of observations. Do you want an empirical cdf of a random draw of 10 observations, or are you looking for the distribution of the sum of 10 independent exponential observations (i.e. a gamma distribution)?

Comment: The distribution doesn't change based on `n` unlike a binomial distribution. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @jeff @allancameron I'm sorry it isn't exactly clear. I was given an exponential distribution with parameter `λ = 1/5` - Now I'm supposed to generate 10 observations that come from said exponential destribution and then plot both a PDF and CPF - I'd guess that it's the result of the sum of 10 independent or random observations since the gamma distribution wasn't mentioned

Comment: Ok, so you're asking 3 questions: pdf, cdf and an example with 10 observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 functions you are looking for are `dexp()`, `qexp()` and `rexp()`. Use the `?` operator to get the help page for them.

Each stat distribution has the equivalent set of functions that define the density, quantiles (cumulative) and a data set.

R uses `plot(x, y)` notation to make a plot. If you are using Rstudio, you can use the GUI to save the image, else you can do:

```
png("name.png")
plot(x, y)
dev.off()
```

I'm not wholly confident on stack overflow's policy on answering homework questions, but I think this isn't overstepping. I think figuring out what goes on the x and y axes constitutes what you're supposed to figure out.